# WSO2 API Manager doesn't work with PostgreSQL integration

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, dockerfile, wso2

My docker image has built using their official repo
https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/master/dockerfiles/apim

I used their documents and had the files required to build it
`init.sh  jdk1.8.0_171  postgresql-42.2.0.jar  wso2am-2.2.0`

I used the following config for master-datasources.xml
http://yasassriratnayake.blogspot.com/2014/07/changing-default-db-of-wso2-api-manger.html

And metrics-datasources.xml similar way.

---

When I run docker then it gives the following logs

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-166:~/docker-apim-2/dockerfiles/apim$ docker run -it -p 9999:9443 wso2am:2.2.0
<>JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /home/wso2carbon/java
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/wso2carbon/wso2am-2.2.0
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
[2018-06-27 13:17:12,698]  INFO - QpidBundleActivator Setting BundleContext in PluginManager
[2018-06-27 13:17:13,945]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2018-06-27 13:17:13,945]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 4.4.0-1061-aws, amd64
[2018-06-27 13:17:13,946]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /home/wso2carbon/java/jre
[2018-06-27 13:17:13,946]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.8.0_171
[2018-06-27 13:17:13,946]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.171-b11,Oracle Corporation
[2018-06-27 13:17:13,947]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /home/wso2carbon/wso2am-2.2.0
[2018-06-27 13:17:13,947]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /home/wso2carbon/wso2am-2.2.0/tmp
[2018-06-27 13:17:13,947]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : wso2carbon, en-US, Etc/UTC
[2018-06-27 13:17:14,252]  INFO - KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2018-06-27 13:17:14,383]  INFO - TemplateDeployerServiceTrackerDS Successfully deployed the execution manager tracker service
[2018-06-27 13:17:16,127]  WARN - ConnectionFactoryImpl ConnectException occurred while connecting to localhost:5432
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

[2018-06-27 13:17:16,141] ERROR - Driver Connection error: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
[2018-06-27 13:17:16,160] ERROR - DefaultRealm nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

[2018-06-27 13:17:16,185] ERROR - Activator Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

[2018-06-27 13:17:25,767]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined </br>
```

My questions are

1. You have build your docker image using mySQL, Is there any way to build image that will be compatible with PostgreSQL?
2. What are the changes required and which files be changed to build with PostgreSQL compatible api-manager image?

Please suggest step by step if you have overcome something like I'm troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

> Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Have you just copy/paste the configuration or did you try to understood what's inside? the system is trying to connect to locahost, but you need to configure a separate database server, [see the docs](https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/61054135)

> You have build your docker image using mySQL, Is there any way to build image that will be compatible with PostgreSQL?

indeed, read the Dockerfile, instead of copying the mysql driver, you can provide a postgresql driver, update the datasource config and you are good to go